# Can't run react-native app on iOS 5 error: duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: javascript, react-native, rn-fetch-blob

Log output:

duplicate symbol '_bridgeRef' in:
/Users/sistemas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppRino-dpmstbwiuaxsmaaznuvxrkhqxixf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-blob-util/libreact-native-blob-util.a(ReactNativeBlobUtil.o)
/Users/sistemas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppRino-dpmstbwiuaxsmaaznuvxrkhqxixf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/rn-fetch-blob/librn-fetch-blob.a(RNFetchBlob.o)
duplicate symbol '_fsQueue' in:
/Users/sistemas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppRino-dpmstbwiuaxsmaaznuvxrkhqxixf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-blob-util/libreact-native-blob-util.a(ReactNativeBlobUtil.o)
/Users/sistemas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppRino-dpmstbwiuaxsmaaznuvxrkhqxixf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/rn-fetch-blob/librn-fetch-blob.a(RNFetchBlob.o)
duplicate symbol '_commonTaskQueue' in:
/Users/sistemas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppRino-dpmstbwiuaxsmaaznuvxrkhqxixf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-blob-util/libreact-native-blob-util.a(ReactNativeBlobUtil.o)
/Users/sistemas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppRino-dpmstbwiuaxsmaaznuvxrkhqxixf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/rn-fetch-blob/librn-fetch-blob.a(RNFetchBlob.o)
duplicate symbol '_fileStreams' in:
/Users/sistemas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppRino-dpmstbwiuaxsmaaznuvxrkhqxixf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-blob-util/libreact-native-blob-util.a(ReactNativeBlobUtilFS.o)
/Users/sistemas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppRino-dpmstbwiuaxsmaaznuvxrkhqxixf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/rn-fetch-blob/librn-fetch-blob.a(RNFetchBlobFS.o)
duplicate symbol '_expirationTable' in:
/Users/sistemas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppRino-dpmstbwiuaxsmaaznuvxrkhqxixf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-blob-util/libreact-native-blob-util.a(ReactNativeBlobUtilNetwork.o)
/Users/sistemas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppRino-dpmstbwiuaxsmaaznuvxrkhqxixf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/rn-fetch-blob/librn-fetch-blob.a(RNFetchBlobNetwork.o)
ld: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is react-native-blob-util is conflicting with rn-fetch-blob , I resolved by removing react-native-blob-util

```
npm uninstall react-native-blob-util 
npm install
cd ios
pod install
```

Comment: Based on the https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-blob-util page, it seems it's the way around : Remove rn-fetch-blob and switch to react-native-blob-util. Anyways, thank you !